# Opencart - how to automaticlly add product to cart when certain conditions are met

Tags: opencart

Is it possible to add certain product(s) to cart when some conditions are met?

For expample: 
My condition is - if is in cart any product from category C then add product X and you can`t delete it form cart if this condition is still active.

Customer adds Product P from category C and system automaticlly adds product X so in cart are two product now.

My goal is to have those two product in invoice as two separate items then. Manually adding that second product is not an option.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: which version you are using of OC ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a method named add under the cart.php Here

```
Catalog->controller->checkout->cart.php
```

In which you get the product id on which user clicked out for add that product in their cart, here you can check your condition that this product belongs from which category. If your condition will be true then you can add another option product to the cart by using this method

```
$this->cart->add($optional-Product_id, $quantity, $option, $recurring_id);

-> by default $quantity will be 1.
-> By default $recurring_id will be 0.
-> And $option would be an array ($option = array()).
```

I hope this will help you a lot.